# Issue with objc property blocks during migration to Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift3, migration, closures

I'm currently trying to migrate a project from Swift 2 to Swift 3 and I'm seeing some issues with some objc property blocks.

I have this objc class:

```
@class Result;
typedef id (^mapResultFunction)(id value);
typedef Result * (^flatMapResultFunction)(id value);

typedef void(^resultSuccess)(id value);
typedef void(^resultFailure)(NSError *error);

@class AsyncResult;
typedef AsyncResult * (^flatMapAsyncResultFunction)(id value);
typedef Result * (^catchFailureResultFunction)(NSError *error);

@interface AsyncResult : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) AsyncResult * (^success)(resultSuccess success);
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) AsyncResult * (^failure)(resultFailure failure);
```

and in Swift 2, this usage is compiling fine:

```
asyncResult
.success { result in
    // show result
}?
.failure { error in
    // show error
}
```

but now with Swift 3, I get this compile error:
`Cannot call value of non-function type '((resultSuccess?) -> AsyncResult?)!'`

I see that the generated Swift code is :

```
public typealias mapResultFunction = (Any?) -> Any?
public typealias flatMapResultFunction = (Any?) -> Result?

public typealias resultSuccess = (Any?) -> Swift.Void
public typealias resultFailure = (Error?) -> Swift.Void

public typealias flatMapAsyncResultFunction = (Any?) -> AsyncResult?
public typealias catchFailureResultFunction = (Error?) -> Result?

open class AsyncResult : NSObject {

    open var success: ((__ObjC.resultSuccess?) -> AsyncResult?)! { get }

    open var failure: ((__ObjC.resultFailure?) -> AsyncResult?)! { get }
}
```

These `__ObjC` look suspicious so I tried to write my own code like this :

```
class AsyncResult {

   var success: (((Any) -> (Void)) -> AsyncResult?)!

   var failure: (((Error) -> Void) -> AsyncResult?)!
}
```

And calling it like this finally works:

```
let r = AsyncResult()

r.success { result in
    print("Hi")
}?.failure { failure in
    print("Error")
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what changed in Swift 3?
And what I can do to fix that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Swift 3.0.2 or 3.1. Please could you provide a fully self-contained example which reproduces the same problem?

Comment: @Hamish you can created a simple project with Cocoapods https://github.com/IanKeen/IKResults.

Comment: I can send you that test project (zipped) if that helps...

Comment: I also have a project with handwritten AsyncResult objc files (no pod). And I'm still seeing the same issue in Swift 3.0.2

Comment: Just cloned your GitHub repo and added a Swift file with the above code – still compiles fine for me in Swift 3.0.2. Have you tried cleaning your build folder?

Comment: @Hamish see my answer. I feel dump for wasting your time here, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit.
The issue was actually inside the closures.

```
asyncResult
.success { result in
    showResult(result)
}?
.failure { error in
    // show error
}
```

when `showResult` is expecting a `AnyObject`. In Swift 3, it's now `Any`...

You would think Xcode would show the error in that line though...